# How to write a test to confirm that a perl script waits (or doesn't wait) for interactive user input (based on supplied options)

Tags: perl, stdin, tty

I have a perl script for which I would like to write a few tests.  If the perl script gets supplied a specific option, the user is allowed to paste or type out multi-line input and end their input using control-d.

These are the tests I want to write:

1. The script (when an interactive flag is supplied) waits for (multiple lines of) input on STDIN until the user hits control-d
2. [this test is already implemented - but provided for completeness] The script (when a flag is supplied that indicates a redirect/pipe) consumes all input on STDIN and does not wait for control-d
3. The script (when no input flag is provided [interactive or redirect]) does not wait for interactive user input

### Test 1 toy example

I wrote a test for test 1 that confirms input was received (it works by the parent test script printing to the child's input handle and the child modifies and prints that input back out), but that test doesn't wait for an end of input signal (e.g. control-d) (which I don't know how to send anyway).  So in other words, I can confirm it receives input, but I don't know how to confirm that it waits for the user to intentionally end the input entry.  I.e. How do I know that the input consumption won't stop until the user types control-d?

Here's what I have so far for test 1.  I wrote a 3rd little `IO::Pipe::Consumer` module to be able to send input to the child process that I'm testing and I wrote a toy example of the script that allows input on STDIN from a tty.

Here is a toy version of the script I'm testing:

```
>perl -e 'while(<STDIN>){print("*$_")}'
test
*test
^d
>
```

And here is the toy test code (that I want to improve) for the above script:

```
>perl -e '
   use IO::Pipe::Consumer;
   $obj = new IO::Pipe::Consumer;
   $si = $obj->getSubroutineConsumer(
      sub { while(<STDIN>) print("*$_") } }
   );
   print $si "test\n"
'
*test
>
```

I thought the parent would have to print an EOF (e.g. like what you get from "control-d") to end the input in the test, but the test ends immediately even though I'm not sending any such end-of-input character.  I can see that it's getting, modifying, and printing the input.  Is that sufficient to confirm that the script will wait for user input (and that the user will be able to intentionally end the input) or is there something else I should do to confirm it waits for *all* user input until the user intends to end it?

### Test 2 - done

### Test 3 toy - don't know how to write it...

Even if modified input spit back out is sufficient proof of "waiting for input" for test 1, I also wish to test that a script *doesn't* consume input on STDIN when no input option (interactive or redirect) is provided - but since it doesn't seem to wait even when I do send it input without an end-of-input signal, how would I test that the script wouldn't hang waiting for input?  Note, the script has other options for consuming redirected or piped input, so my intent is specifically to know if it's waiting on input from the tty.  All of the STDIN consumption options (whether from the tty or via redirect/pipe) are optional, which is why I want to write these tests.

My manual testing shows everything works as intended.  I would just like some tests to assure that behavior for the future.

### IO::Pipe::Consumer

I feel like the thing I'm missing is not relevant to `IO::Pipe::Consumer`, so WRT that, I'll just describe it instead of paste in 30 or so lines of code... All it does is it sets a pipe to the child's STDIN and gives that handle back to the parent for it to print to.  I haven't put it on cpan.  I'm just experimenting to see if I can use it to write these tests.

`IO::Pipe::Consumer` is basically the opposite of `IO::Pipe::Producer` (a module I published on cpan looong ago, say 2001-ish, when I was new to perl, or programming for that matter).  The main difference, aside from swapping `STDIN` for `STDOUT` and `Reader` with `Writer` (and vice versa), is that the open is `open(STDIN,"<",\${$stdin_pipe})`.

Comment: Maybe I can test to see if the child process has ended after the print to it?  If it has ended, it means it's not waiting on input...? But I think it should remain running until its standard handles are closed whether it's waiting on input or not, right?

Comment: Could you please specify the question(s) you are asking with clarity.

Answer (score 1):

> *I thought the parent would have to print an "end-of-input" (e.g. "control-d") character to end the input in the test,*

Ctrl-D doesn't produce an "end of input character"; it causes the terminal to return EOF.

I don't know what IO::Pipe::Consumer is —it's not on CPAN— but I presume it creates a pipe. Exiting the program causes the writer end of the pipe to be closed and thus cause the reader end to return EOF.

> *is there something else I should do to confirm it waits for all user input until the user intends to end it?*

`<>` reads until one of the following things happen:

- A line feed is encountered (returning what was read including the line feed)
- EOF is encountered (returning what was read up to an including the line feed)
- An error is encountered (returning false).

You can confirm it waits by putting sleep statements between what you send. Be aware that buffering may interfere.

Comment: So control-d produces an "end-of-file" (i.e. EOF) character. Sorry, that's what's what I meant, but wasn't sure if that's specifically what control-d sent.  How would I (or can I) print the EOF character to the child's input pipe? You're right about `IO::Pipe::Consumer`. It isn't on cpan.  By "I wrote a 3rd little IO::Pipe::Consumer module", I meant to convey I *just* wrote it. Sorry for the confusion. Let me see if I can make the question less stream-of-conciousness.

Comment: Re "*So control-d produces an "end-of-file" (i.e. EOF) character.*", That is NOT correct, and NOT what I said

Comment: Re "*I meant to convey I just wrote it.*", That was for the benefit of readers of my answer.

Comment: Ok. I misunderstood. I always assumed EOF was a character I guess. So where and how does the terminal "return EOF" and what is EOF? Is it a signal like KILL? How does the script "encounter" it? Is it on the STDIN pipe?

Comment: Different IO functions handle EOF differently. Check the appropriate docs. I already said how `readline` (`<>`) indicates EOF.

Comment: OK, sorry if I'm incorrectly interpreting what you said.  I'm just trying to understand.  So does that mean that EOF is read by `readline` (`<>`) on the input stream? I must have it wrong because you said I was incorrect when I inferred that control-d does not result in an EOF character. I modified my question to try and make it clearer at your request. One concern I have is that for test 3 to be a good test - it would have to fail well, i.e. not just hang if the script being tested does consume and wait on STDIN.

Comment: You said readline will respond to EOF. How do I intentionally test that? I.e. how do I return or send EOF?

Comment: For a pipe, close the writer (and all dups of it, including those inherited by children)